# How to integration Stripe payment gateway in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I would like to integerate stripe payment gateway in codeigniter. I previously uses core php library of stripe and it works fine but in codeigniter how i integerate it in codeigniter.

my files are like below :
view:

```
<?php //echo form_open('vendor/stripe_charge'); ?>
                                <input type="text" name="data-key" value="<?php echo "pk_test_lWC3x0aqak9UBnQy6JnRTGOL";//echo $config['publishable_key']; ?>"/>
                                <input type="text" name="data-amount" value="5000"/>
                                <input type="text" name="data-description" value="Paying your bill"/>
                                <input type="text" name="data-name" value="Yummylicious"/>
                                <input type="text" name="data-image" value="http://interiorlounge.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/logo_huawei_128x128.jpg"/>
                                <input type="text" name="data-label" value="Pay Your Bill"/>
                                <input type="submit" value="Pay Your Bill"/>
                            <!--
                              // optional parameters in javascript
                             data-shipping-address="true"
                            data-billing-address="true"  -->
                            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

"/>

controller :

```
public function stripe_charge(){
        echo "stripe function working"."<br>";
        echo $this->input->post('amount');
        Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_yDE2WSUQ3wexrlhqO01PeANe");
}
```

and error occurs :
stripe function working
Fatal error: Class 'Stripe' not found in D:\xamp\htdocs\halal_lte\application\controllers\vendor.php on line 578

Comment: try with `\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_yDE2WSUQ3wexrlhqO01PeANe');`

Comment: I actually wants to know that where to place the library files and how to include it in my project because it says me that not stripe class is found , it seems to me that i am not placing it in the right directory or linking it incorrectly.

Comment: https://github.com/calvinfroedge/codeigniter-payments may help you

Comment: where is your Stripe class??

Comment: can you help me @abdullahshoaib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place stripe library into system/libaries then

`` $stripe = array(
            "secret_key" => STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,
            "publishable_key" => STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
        );
    try { 
          \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
           ---and do what you want to do--- 
        }  catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
            // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
            $body = $e->getJsonBody();`enter code here`
            $err = $body['error'];
            return $err['message'];
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
            // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            $body = $e->getJsonBody();
            $err = $body['error'];
            return $err['message'];
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
            // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
            // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
            $body = $e->getJsonBody();
            $err = $body['error'];
            return $err['message'];
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
            // Network communication with Stripe failed
            $body = $e->getJsonBody();
            $err = $body['error'];
            return $err['message'];
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
            // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            // yourself an email
            $body = $e->getJsonBody();
            $err = $body['error'];
            return $err['message'];
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
            $body = $e->getJsonBody();
            $err = $body['error'];
            return $err['message'];
        }</pre> ``

Comment: I actually wants to know that where to place the library files and how to include it in my project because it says me that not stripe class is found , it seems to me that i am not placing it in the right directory or linking it incorrectly.

Comment: Place stripe library into system/libaries

Comment: create a folder Stripe under system/libararies and download stripe library from here https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/archive/v3.0.0.zip and extract the content into "Stripe" folder

Comment: can you help me? @JasbirSinghSohanpal

Answer (score 0):

download [stripe.php](https://github.com/bcessa/php-stripe/blob/master/Stripe.php) if you don't have and place this into `app/protected/components`. components should be autoloaded from `main.php`

```
'import'=>array(
        ..
        'application.components.*',
        ..
    ),
```

now you can use

`Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_yDE2WSUQ3wexrlhqO01PeANe");`

Answer (score 0):

If u have already prepared Library  than u need to put it in application/library folder.

I suggest that u unzip all files on your computer maybe u will have config  files which u need to put in config folder and u need to go over readme.md file to get all needed information.

and u need to check maybe u need Dependency Management for PHP[(Composer)](https://getcomposer.org/)

to run that libary.